# How to create delimited file using BeanWriter

Tags: java, apache-camel, bean-io

I am able to create file but the output file is not containing the delimiter , It is having fixedlength delimiter. How do I make it use my delimiter provided in beanio json

Below is the Code which I have tried for writing the file but it does not give the expected output

```
String qualifiedChannelName = programId + "_" + channel;

    BeanWriter out = factory.createWriter(qualifiedChannelName, new File("D:\\dataengine\\files\\40287a35725ae63e0172934c765d0014\\tm.txt"));

    for (Transaction e : transactions) {
        out.write(e);
    }
    out.flush();
    out.close();
```

This is my bean io file format

```
[ { \"key\": \"beanio.transaction.sku.streamname\", \"value\": \"SKU\" }, { \"key\": \"beanio.transaction.payment.streamname\", \"value\": \"PAYMENT\" }, { \"key\": \"transaction.payment.identifier\", \"value\": \"12\" }, { \"key\": \"transaction.sku.identifier\", \"value\": \"11\" }, { \"key\": \"create.ghost.customer.from.card\", \"value\": \"true\" }, { \"key\": \"beanio.fileHeadercustomer.streamname\", \"value\": \"Header\" }, { \"key\": \"tenant.useHeader\", \"value\": \"false\" }, { \"key\": \"beanio.fileHeaderTransaction.streamname\", \"value\": \"Header\" }, { \"key\": \"transaction.fileheader.identifier\", \"value\": \"00\" }, { \"key\": \"beanio.card.streamname\", \"value\": \"Card\" }, { \"key\": \"customer.record.identifier\", \"value\": \"10\" }, { \"key\": \"beanio.transaction.streamname\", \"value\": \"Transaction\" }, { \"key\": \"card.fileheader.identifier\", \"value\": \"00\" }, { \"key\": \"customer.fileheader.identifier\", \"value\": \"00\" }, { \"key\": \"beanio.account.streamname\", \"value\": \"\" }, { \"key\": \"beanio.configuration\", \"value\": \"\\u003C?xml version=\\\"1.0\\\"?> <beanio xmlns=\\\"http://www.beanio.org/2012/03\\\" xmlns:xsi=\\\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\\\" xsi:schemaLocation=\\\"http://www.beanio.org/2012/03 http://www.beanio.org/2012/03/mapping.xsd\\\"> <stream name=\\\"40287a35725ae63e0172934c765d0014_AJIO_ONLINE\\\" format=\\\"delimited\\\"> <parser class=\\\"com.loylty.dataacquisition.util.CustomDelimitedBeanIOParserFactory\\\"> <property name=\\\"customDelimiter\\\" value=\\\"\\\\\\\\^\\\"><\\/property> <\\/parser> <typeHandler type=\\\"java.util.Date\\\" class=\\\"com.loylty.dataacquisition.util.CustomDateTypeHandler\\\"> <property name=\\\"pattern\\\" value=\\\"dd-MMM-yyyy\\\"/> <\\/typeHandler> <typeHandler type=\\\"java.math.BigDecimal\\\" class=\\\"com.loylty.dataacquisition.util.BigDecimalHandler\\\"/> <typeHandler name=\\\"negativeHandler\\\" class=\\\"com.loylty.dataacquisition.util.NegativeBigDecimalHandler\\\"/> <record name=\\\"Transaction\\\" class=\\\"com.loylty.dataacquisition.entities.Transaction\\\" maxLength=\\\"17\\\" minLength=\\\"17\\\" > <field name=\\\"paymentProcessor\\\" trim=\\\"true\\\" lazy=\\\"true\\\" maxLength=\\\"100\\\" /> <field name=\\\"transactionId\\\" trim=\\\"true\\\" lazy=\\\"true\\\" maxLength=\\\"100\\\" /> <field name=\\\"merchantName\\\" trim=\\\"true\\\" lazy=\\\"true\\\" maxLength=\\\"100\\\" /> <field name=\\\"merchantTransactionId\\\" trim=\\\"true\\\" lazy=\\\"true\\\" maxLength=\\\"100\\\" /> <field name=\\\"terminalId\\\" trim=\\\"true\\\" lazy=\\\"true\\\" maxLength=\\\"100\\\" /> <field name=\\\"merchantId\\\" trim=\\\"true\\\" lazy=\\\"true\\\" maxLength=\\\"100\\\" /> <field name=\\\"terminalOwnerName\\\" trim=\\\"true\\\" lazy=\\\"true\\\" maxLength=\\\"100\\\" /> <field name=\\\"first6DigitCard\\\" trim=\\\"true\\\" lazy=\\\"true\\\" maxLength=\\\"100\\\" /> <field name=\\\"last4DigitCard\\\" trim=\\\"true\\\" lazy=\\\"true\\\" maxLength=\\\"100\\\" /> <field name=\\\"cardTypeCode\\\" trim=\\\"true\\\" lazy=\\\"true\\\" maxLength=\\\"100\\\" /> <field name=\\\"cardIssuer\\\" trim=\\\"true\\\" lazy=\\\"true\\\" maxLength=\\\"100\\\" /> <field name=\\\"acquirerId\\\" trim=\\\"true\\\" lazy=\\\"true\\\" maxLength=\\\"100\\\" /> <field name=\\\"transactionType\\\" trim=\\\"true\\\" lazy=\\\"true\\\" maxLength=\\\"100\\\" /> <field name=\\\"transactionAmount\\\" trim=\\\"true\\\" lazy=\\\"true\\\" maxLength=\\\"100\\\" /> <field name=\\\"transactionDate\\\" trim=\\\"true\\\" lazy=\\\"true\\\" maxLength=\\\"100\\\" /> <field name=\\\"transactionTime\\\" regex=\\\"([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]\\\" trim=\\\"true\\\" lazy=\\\"true\\\" maxLength=\\\"100\\\" /> <field name=\\\"postDate\\\" trim=\\\"true\\\" lazy=\\\"true\\\" maxLength=\\\"100\\\" /> <\\/record> <\\/stream> <stream name=\\\"40287a35725ae63e0172934c765d0014_AJIO_ONLINE_REFUND\\\" format=\\\"delimited\\\"> <parser class=\\\"com.loylty.dataacquisition.util.CustomDelimitedBeanIOParserFactory\\\"> <property name=\\\"customDelimiter\\\" value=\\\"\\\\\\\\^\\\"><\\/property> <\\/parser> <typeHandler type=\\\"java.util.Date\\\" class=\\\"com.loylty.dataacquisition.util.CustomDateTypeHandler\\\"> <property name=\\\"pattern\\\" value=\\\"dd-MMM-yyyy\\\"/> <\\/typeHandler> <typeHandler type=\\\"java.math.BigDecimal\\\" class=\\\"com.loylty.dataacquisition.util.BigDecimalHandler\\\"/> <typeHandler name=\\\"negativeHandler\\\" class=\\\"com.loylty.dataacquisition.util.NegativeBigDecimalHandler\\\"/> <record name=\\\"Transaction\\\" class=\\\"com.loylty.dataacquisition.entities.Transaction\\\" maxLength=\\\"17\\\" minLength=\\\"17\\\" > <field name=\\\"paymentProcessor\\\" trim=\\\"true\\\" lazy=\\\"true\\\" maxLength=\\\"100\\\" /> <field name=\\\"transactionId\\\" trim=\\\"true\\\" lazy=\\\"true\\\" maxLength=\\\"100\\\" /> <field name=\\\"merchantName\\\" trim=\\\"true\\\" lazy=\\\"true\\\" maxLength=\\\"100\\\" /> <field name=\\\"merchantTransactionId\\\" trim=\\\"true\\\" lazy=\\\"true\\\" maxLength=\\\"100\\\" /> <field name=\\\"terminalId\\\" trim=\\\"true\\\" lazy=\\\"true\\\" maxLength=\\\"100\\\" /> <field name=\\\"merchantId\\\" trim=\\\"true\\\" lazy=\\\"true\\\" maxLength=\\\"100\\\" /> <field name=\\\"terminalOwnerName\\\" trim=\\\"true\\\" lazy=\\\"true\\\" maxLength=\\\"100\\\" /> <field name=\\\"first6DigitCard\\\" trim=\\\"true\\\" lazy=\\\"true\\\" maxLength=\\\"100\\\" /> <field name=\\\"last4DigitCard\\\" trim=\\\"true\\\" lazy=\\\"true\\\" maxLength=\\\"100\\\" /> <field name=\\\"cardTypeCode\\\" trim=\\\"true\\\" lazy=\\\"true\\\" maxLength=\\\"100\\\" /> <field name=\\\"cardIssuer\\\" trim=\\\"true\\\" lazy=\\\"true\\\" maxLength=\\\"100\\\" /> <field name=\\\"acquirerId\\\" trim=\\\"true\\\" lazy=\\\"true\\\" maxLength=\\\"100\\\" /> <field name=\\\"transactionType\\\" trim=\\\"true\\\" lazy=\\\"true\\\" maxLength=\\\"100\\\" /> <field name=\\\"transactionAmount\\\" trim=\\\"true\\\" lazy=\\\"true\\\" maxLength=\\\"100\\\" /> <field name=\\\"transactionDate\\\" trim=\\\"true\\\" lazy=\\\"true\\\" maxLength=\\\"100\\\" /> <field name=\\\"transactionTime\\\" regex=\\\"([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]\\\" trim=\\\"true\\\" lazy=\\\"true\\\" maxLength=\\\"100\\\" /> <field name=\\\"postDate\\\" trim=\\\"true\\\" lazy=\\\"true\\\" maxLength=\\\"100\\\" /> <\\/record> <\\/stream> <\\/beanio>\\r\\n\" }, { \"key\": \"beanio.fileHeaderaccount.streamname\", \"value\": \"\" }, { \"key\": \"account.fileheader.identifier\", \"value\": \"00\" }, { \"key\": \"beanio.customer.streamname\", \"value\": \"Customer\" }, { \"key\": \"account.record.identifier\", \"value\": \"11\" }, { \"key\": \"card.record.identifier\", \"value\": \"12\" }, { \"key\": \"camel.routes\", \"value\": \"\\u003C?xml version=\\\"1.0\\\"?> <routes xmlns=\\\"http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring\\\"> <route startupOrder=\\\"1\\\" id=\\\"download\\\" autoStartup=\\\"false\\\"> <from uri=\\\"sftp://lradmin@192.168.250.204:22/../../../../files/40287a35725ae63e0172934c765d0014/sftp?password=Lrp@1234&amp;sendEmptyMessageWhenIdle=true&amp;move=.done&amp;delay=15000&amp;readLock=readLockCheckInterval&amp;disconnectOnBatchComplete=true\\\" /> <choice> <when> <simple>${header.CamelFileNameOnly} == null<\\/simple> <\\/when> <otherwise> <to uri =\\\"file:/dataengine/files/40287a35725ae63e0172934c765d0014\\\" /> <\\/otherwise> <\\/choice> <onCompletion> <filter> <log message=\\\"download thread completed\\\"><\\/log> <simple>${property.CamelBatchComplete} == true<\\/simple> <to uri=\\\"direct:completeddownload\\\"/> <\\/filter> <\\/onCompletion> <\\/route> <route id=\\\"handback\\\" autoStartup=\\\"false\\\"> <from uri =\\\"file:/dataengine/files/40287a35725ae63e0172934c765d0014?include=.*\\\\.handback&amp;delay=15000&amp;sendEmptyMessageWhenIdle=true\\\" /> <choice> <when> <simple>${body} == null<\\/simple> <\\/when> <otherwise> <to uri=\\\"sftp://lradmin@192.168.250.204:22/../../files/40287a35725ae63e0172934c765d0014/handback?password=Lrp@1234&amp;sendEmptyMessageWhenIdle=true&amp;disconnectOnBatchComplete=true\\\" /> <\\/otherwise> <\\/choice> <onCompletion> <filter> <log message=\\\"HandBack thread completed\\\"><\\/log> <simple>${property.CamelBatchComplete} == true<\\/simple> <to uri=\\\"direct:completedhandback\\\"/> <\\/filter> <\\/onCompletion> <\\/route> <route> <from uri=\\\"direct:completeddownload\\\" /> <to uri=\\\"controlbus:route?routeId=download&amp;action=stop&amp;async=true\\\" /> <\\/route> <route> <from uri=\\\"direct:completedhandback\\\" /> <to uri=\\\"controlbus:route?routeId=handback&amp;action=stop&amp;async=true\\\" /> <\\/route> <route startupOrder=\\\"2\\\" id=\\\"AJIO_ONLINE\\\" autoStartup=\\\"false\\\"> <from uri=\\\"file:/dataengine/files/40287a35725ae63e0172934c765d0014/?include=POS.*\\\\.txt&amp;sendEmptyMessageWhenIdle=true&amp;delay=5000&amp;sortBy=date:file:yyyyMMdd;file:name\\\"/> <onCompletion> <filter> <simple>${property.CamelBatchComplete} == true<\\/simple> <to uri=\\\"direct:completedAJIO_ONLINE\\\"/> <\\/filter> <\\/onCompletion> <setHeader headerName=\\\"fileType\\\"> <simple>TRANSACTION<\\/simple> <\\/setHeader> <setheader headerName=\\\"channel\\\"> <simple>AJIO_ONLINE<\\/simple> <\\/setheader> <setHeader headerName=\\\"programId\\\"> <simple>40287a35725ae63e0172934c765d0014<\\/simple> <\\/setHeader> <to uri=\\\"bean:genericFileProcessorImpl?method=processOnlinePartner\\\"/> <\\/route> <route> <from uri=\\\"direct:completedAJIO_ONLINE\\\" /> <to uri=\\\"controlbus:route?routeId=AJIO_ONLINE&amp;action=stop&amp;async=true\\\" /> <\\/route> <route startupOrder=\\\"3\\\" id=\\\"AJIO_ONLINE_REFUND\\\" autoStartup=\\\"false\\\"> <from uri=\\\"file:/dataengine/files/40287a35725ae63e0172934c765d0014/?include=refundpos.*\\\\.txt&amp;sendEmptyMessageWhenIdle=true&amp;delay=5000&amp;sortBy=date:file:yyyyMMdd;file:name\\\"/> <onCompletion> <filter> <simple>${property.CamelBatchComplete} == true<\\/simple> <to uri=\\\"direct:completedAJIO_ONLINE_REFUND\\\"/> <\\/filter> <\\/onCompletion> <setHeader headerName=\\\"fileType\\\"> <simple>REFUND<\\/simple> <\\/setHeader> <setheader headerName=\\\"channel\\\"> <simple>AJIO_ONLINE_REFUND<\\/simple> <\\/setheader> <setHeader headerName=\\\"programId\\\"> <simple>40287a35725ae63e0172934c765d0014<\\/simple> <\\/setHeader> <to uri=\\\"bean:genericFileProcessorImpl?method=processOnlinePartner\\\"/> <\\/route> <route> <from uri=\\\"direct:completedAJIO_ONLINE_REFUND\\\" /> <to uri=\\\"controlbus:route?routeId=AJIO_ONLINE_REFUND&amp;action=stop&amp;async=true\\\" /> <\\/route> <\\/routes>\" }, { \"key\": \"create.ghost.account.from.card\", \"value\": \"true\" }, { \"key\": \"beanio.fileHeadercard.streamname\", \"value\": \"\" }, { \"key\": \"transaction.record.identifier\", \"value\": \"10\" } ]
```

**TRANSACTION.JAVA**

```
public class Transaction {

private String header;
private String uniqueCustomerId;
private String debitCardnumber;
private String first4digitAccountnumber;
private String last4digitsAccountnumber;
private String terminalId;
private String merchantId;
private Date transactionDate;
private String transactionTime;
private String postDate;
private String terminalLocation;
private String terminalOwnerName;
private String terminalCity;
private String terminalState;
private String terminalCountry;
private BigDecimal transactionAmount;
private String transactionId;
private String acquirerId;
private String first6DigitCard;
private String last4DigitCard;
private String merchantCategorycode;
private String transactionType;
private boolean isCardValidated = false;
private boolean isAccountValidated = false;
private boolean isCustomerValidated = false;
private boolean isBinValidated = false;
private String accountNumber;
private String storeId;
private String storeCode;
private String cashier;
private String posId;
private String source;
private String isSuccessful;
private String responseCode;
private String currencyCode;
private BigDecimal fee;
private String addressLine1;
private String addressLine2;
private BigDecimal settlementAmount;
private String zip;
private String atmTransactionType;

// BOM
private String cardTypeCode;

// Transaction Meta info
private String fileName;        // supplied by camel in exchange object
private String channel;         // supplied by client during config
private FileType objectType;      // supplied by client during config

// Some random attributes ?
private BigDecimal transactionInitialAmount;
private BigDecimal vatAmount;
private BigDecimal redeemAmount;
private BigDecimal voucherAmount;

public String getCardTypeCode() {
    return cardTypeCode;
}

public void setCardTypeCode(String cardTypeCode) {
    this.cardTypeCode = cardTypeCode;
}

private BigDecimal netPayable;
private BigDecimal tax;
private BigDecimal discountAmount;
private BigDecimal redeemedAmount;
private String redemptionReferenceId;

private String recordData;

// Refund related attributes
private String originalTransactionId;
private Date originalTransactionDate;
private String originalTransactionTime;
private BigDecimal originalAmount;

// Non-transaction attributes
private String eventName;
private String eventCategory;
private int points;

private List<TransactionPayment> transactionPayments;
private List<TransactionSKU> transactionSKUs;
private Map<String, Float> transactionTax;

private int version;

private BigDecimal adjustmentAmount;

// Yes DC
private String primaryCardIdentifier;

//  PHFL and HDFC Exclusive
private String category;
private String product;

// TMB
private String isOnlineTransaction;

private Long fileId;
// AJIO(ONLINE_PARTNER TXNS field)
private String merchantName;
private String merchantTransactionId;
private String cardIssuer;
private String lrTransactionId;
private String partnerProgramId;

private String paymentProcessor;
 }
```

**EXISTING OUTPUT**

```
BILLDESK    RUR28350404633  AJIO    pay_sp_4a7caa2b-28bf-11ea-83ae-f1c5f19c7fb3 BDR00001    0000000BDR00001 AJIO    324145  4164    SALE    1401.0  24-Mar-2020 13:58:52
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
BILLDESK^RUR28350404633^AJIO^pay_sp_4a7caa2b-28bf-11ea-83ae-f1c5f19c7fb3^BDR00001^0000000BDR00001^AJIO^324145^4164^SALE^1401.0^24-Mar-2020^13:58:52^
```

Comment: Is this Apache Camel's way of configuring BeanIO? Normally there would be annotations or a mapping.xml file that configure BeanIO. I don't see anything in your configuration that could potentially tell BeanIO that it is a `delimited` file format and not a `fixed-length` format. PS: you should probably remove any sensitive information from your post like the location of the sftp server and the credentials.

Comment: check my latest edits . added XML

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you need a custom parser for BeanIO

```xml
<parser class="com.loylty.dataacquisition.util.CustomDelimitedBeanIOParserFactory"> 
  <property name="customDelimiter" value="^" />
</parser>
```

Try configuring the default parser using:

```xml
<parser>
  <property name="delimiter" value="^" />
</parser>
```

Comment: We have multiple file sources and from each sources delimiter can vary

Comment: Ok, lets try and narrow it down then, first set the default delimiter and check that it works correctly, then we go further into changes that is not done by the standard mapping file

Comment: Can you debug the application and then check whether your `CustomDelimitedBeanIOParserFactory` is called and working correctly?

Comment: With my `CustomDelimitedBeanIOParserFactory ` it works